# Running ant from a batch file: Later commands don't run

Tags: ant, copy, batch-file

I have a batch file that runs ant and then copies one of the files that were produced:

```
ant -Dproject.version=1.1.2 release published
copy /Y D:\dir1\MyJar.jar   D:\dir2\MyJar.jar
```

When I run the batch file, ant runs successfully, but the copy statement never happens, although it will work just fine if I type it in and hit Enter after the ant task has finished.

What is going on here?

Comment: "never happens" - without any messages? Maybe running directory is not the same as you try to run it manually?

Answer (score 47, accepted):

I had the same problem once and the magic `call` did it.

In that batch file of yours try:

```
call ant -Dproject.version=1.1.2 release published
copy /Y D:\dir1\MyJar.jar   D:\dir2\MyJar.jar
```

Cannot tell you why it worked, though. Guess it's Microsoft logic.

Comment: This is because `ant` is a batch file. If you are calling one batch from another you need to use `call`. But yes, that's sometimes not very clear.

Comment: It works as long as you don't direct the output of ant to a file: call ant target >> log.log. Then it doesn't continue.

Answer (score 11):

When you call one batch file from another (which is not always clear) you're supposed to use `CALL` (or `call`), otherwise it works more like `goto` and doesn't return back to the caller.  Is `ant` actually a batch file `ant.bat`?  This should work then:

```
CALL ant -Dproject.version=1.1.2 release published
```