# batch scripting + ant - stop cmd prompt from auto exiting

Tags: ant, batch-file

i have an ant build.xml that does some building stuff. Before i execute this though, i need some variables/environment to be set. i am using `.bat` script to do that, and also trying to call `ant` directly from there, so that i dont have to do 2 steps.

Although the script calls the ant target alright, the command prompt window auto exits as soon as the ant build is complete(irrespective of build failure/success)

i have tried `pause` and also `cmd /k`
neither of them have seemed to work.

the `.bat` file looks something like this:

```
@echo off
call C:/somefile.bat
ant targetName
pause
cmd /k
```

Comment: duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4390732/running-ant-from-a-batch-file-later-commands-dont-run

Answer (score 15, accepted):

If the ant script is a console app then you will need to `call` that also, otherwise control will be transferred to it and never return to the batch

```
@echo off
call C:/somefile.bat
call ant targetName
pause
```